# How to adjust bootstrap 3 input-group width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I adjust the bootstrap input group width and still have it be responsive. For example I only want the quantity input field to take x%(be much smaller) than description field. Also how do I wrap each input field on mobile? Thanks in advance, sorry I am a Noob.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
<div class="col-lg-10">
  <div class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center"><strong>Store Transfer</strong></div>

 <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="col-lg-12">

     <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Description</span>
       <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Item Description">

       <span class="input-group-addon">Quantity</span>
       <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Quantity">

       <span class="input-group-addon">Cost</span>
       <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Cost">

       <span class="input-group-addon">Total $0.00</span>
       </div>

     </div>
   </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>   
    <div class="col-lg-8">
   <div class="form-group">

    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">Transfer From:</span>

    <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        <option value="store" disabled="" selected="" class="">Select Store</option>
                        <option value="Richfield" class="">Richfield</option>
                        <option value="Eagan" class="">Eagan</option>
  </select>

  <span class="input-group-addon">Transfer To:</span>

   <select class="form-control">
                        <option value="store" disabled="" selected="" class="">Select Store</option>
                        <option value="Richfield" class="">Richfield</option>
                        <option value="Eagan" class="">Eagan</option>
  </select>

  <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:0px; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; border:none;"></span>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Submit</button>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>






   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    </div>

 </div>

  </div>
```

[BootPly Here](https://www.bootply.com/4ve1YtsXcy)

[image: Pic of panel]

Comment: Do you have a picture of your ideal result so we know what exactly you're looking for?

Comment: updated with pic, also bootply should have image if you click run on code.